# Support passing from Scenario Outline to JSON file

Tags: karate

I am going to reuse some features and calling multiple features in a Scenario Outline. 
Since the features being called are common, we would like to define its parameters in its own parameter file, while the parameter values are defined in placeholder.

We hope the placeholder can get the value from the Outline Examples.

How to make it?

```
Feature: verify parameter passing

  Scenario Outline: verify 2 calls
    * def result1 = call read('baseFeature1.feature')

    * def result2 = call read('baseFeature2.feature') result1

    * print result2

    Examples:
      | fooValue |
      | value1 |
      | value2 |
```

```
Feature: feature to verify the parameter passing, no input parameter

Scenario: feature 1

  Given def payload = read('classpath:feature_1.json')

  * print 'feature 1' + payload

  Given def result = { "barValue": "barValue"}
```

```
Feature: feature to verify the parameter passing, with input parameter from last step

Scenario: feature 2

  Given def payload = read('classpath:feature_2.json')

  * print payload
```

feature_1.json

```
{
  "foo": "#(fooValue)"
}
```

feature_2.json

```
{
  "foo": "fooValue",
  "bar": "#(result1.barValue)"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the version currently in development will make this possible. Can you take a look at this GitHub issue and see if this addresses your question: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/717

It will also be great if you can build from source and try this new capability.

```
Scenario Outline: magic variables with embedded expressions
  * def expected = __num == 0 ? { name: 'Bob', alive: false } : { name: 'Nyan', alive: true }
  * match expected == { name: '#(__row.name)', alive: '#(__row.alive)' }
  * eval karate.set(__row)
  # you can read from a re-usable JSON file instead of the line below
  * match expected == { name: '#(name)', alive: '#(alive)' }

  Examples:
    | name | alive! |
    | Bob  | false  |
    | Nyan | true   |
```

Comment: we can try with this new feature, and how about the release date?

Comment: @wenxzhen you can try now with 0.9.3.RC1 and check. there will be an RC2 within a week. if you provide feedback we can release final sooner :)

Comment: it works.   @peter-thomas

Another requirement on the requirement passing is describe as below, is it possible? If not, how much work we need to do?  

`
Examples:
    | reqParameter1 | reqParameter2 |
    | { "k11": "v11", "k12": "v12"} | { "k13": "v13", "k14": "v14"} |
    | { "k21": "v21", "k22": "v22"} | { "k23": "v23", "k24": "v24"} |
`

the **reqParameters1** and **reqParameter2** can be injected into JSON file, and the keys can be referred as **reqParameters1.k11**, **reqParameter2.k13**?

so that we can reduce the columns of the **Examples** and the conflict.

Comment: @wenxzhen yes you can use `reqParameter!` as the column name, and it will work as you expect, see this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/44b1e0e2cac5a043b17f75ce799e2a3f42fb9fb6/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/outline.feature#L44

Comment: From the example, the **expected** comes as a whole string, but if we wanna extract some keys from **expected**?

Comment: @wenxzhen you can always do `reqParameter.v11` etc.

Comment: `Feature: verify json file

  Scenario Outline: call json file
    * eval karate.set(__row)

    * print "Parameter1", parameter1
    * assert parameter1 == '{ key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}'

    * print "Parameter1", karate.pretty(parameter1)
    * assert parameter1.key1 == "value1"

    * print "Parameter1.key1: ", parameter1.key1

  Examples:
    | parameter1 |
    | { key1: "value1", key2: "value2"} |`

Comment: After the **eval karate.set(__row)**, the **parameter1** is not a JSON type, but in String type, that would be the problem

How to work around it?

Comment: it is fixed in github. build from source please as I said

Comment: OK, will build from branch develop for verification

Comment: In the examples table, we add !, and it works.

previously I wrongly think **!** is only for number and boolean.